# Simple calculation from user input

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time dealing with HTML and javascript, so pardon this simple question. I am trying to calculate the cost total cost of the fruits that the user wants to purchase. It was working fine earlier on but somehow it stopped working. May I know what is wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="orderForm" action="orderProcess.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <h1>My header</h1>
      <label>User Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username"> <br>

      <label>Number of Apples ($0.69 / ea): </label> 
      <input type="text" name="AppleQty" id="AppleQty" oninput="calculateCost()"> <br>

      <label>Number of Oranges ($0.59 / ea): </label>
      <input type="text" name="OrangeQty" id="OrangeQty" oninput="calculateCost()"> <br>

      <label>Number of Bananas ($0.39 / ea): </label>
      <input type="text" name="BananaQty" id="BananaQty" oninput="calculateCost()"> <br>

      <label>Total Cost: $</label>
      <input type="text" name="totalCost" id="totalCost" readonly> <br>
</body>    


<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateCost()
    {
        var appleQty = document.getElementById("AppleQty");
        var orangeQty = document.getElementById("OrangeQty");
        var bananaQty = document.getElementById("BananaQty");
        if(isNaN(appleQty.value))
        {
            alert('Only Numeric Values Allowed');
            appleQty.value = '';
            appleQty.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(isNaN(bananaQty.value))
        {
            alert('Only Numeric Values Allowed');
            bananaQty.value = '';
            bananaQty.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(isNaN(orangeQty.value))
        {
            alert('Only Numeric Values Allowed');
            orangeQty.value = '';
            orangeQty.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("totalCost").value = (appleQty.value * 0.69 + orangeQty.value * 0.59 + bananaQty.value * 0.39).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its JavaScript and not java...

Comment: This does not look Java! I think you meant Javascript!

Comment: Indeed, I messed up with the curly braces on other parts of the code.